# Laravel 8 - How to redirect on error 404?

Tags: php, laravel-8

I know that in Laravel 8 < x method `render()` appears and allows us to handle redirection after errors. I switched to Laravel 8, but in `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` got only method `register()`.

How I can possibly handle redirect to specific route from f.e. `Error 404` or others?

Comment: when exactly did you get the Error 404? For example if you return that error when the ModelNotFoundException is thrown you can create custum exception handler where you can redirect on any route when that Custom Exception is thrown

Comment: I mean I want the redirection to f.e. `/home` when the route isn't defined.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to redirect all 404s to your home page? It's generally advised to not do this.